# Can you Eliminate (x)??

Tags: trigonometry

I wish to find an equation involving only $M$ and $N$ such that $x$ has been eliminated from these two equations.

$$M=\tan x+\cot x$$

$$N=\sec x-\cos x$$

I got this from my friend about  a week ago and I have been trying this for a long time but still haven't been able to eliminate $x$.

Comment: are this two equations?

Comment: Yes two equation m and n

Comment: but it is not a system?

Comment: Eliminate x means. You have to form a relation from the equtions given above where there is no trigonometric identity.Only M and N is there.

Comment: $M =a/b +b/a$ and $N/b = 1/b^2 -1$, where $a = sin(x)$ and $b = cos(x)$.

Comment: Now do u all understand

Comment: Try to understand and then unvote me

Comment: I think this question is reasonable. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that

$M^2 = \tan^2(x)+\cot^2(x)+2$

$N^2 = \sec^2(x)+\cos^2(x)-2$

So $M^2-N^2 = \cot^2(x)-\cos^2(x)+3$, which yields $M^2-N^2-3 = \frac{\cos^4(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$ (*).

Also note $\cot(x)M = \csc^2(x)$ and $\cos(x)N = \sin^2(x)$. Multiplying these two equations and squaring gives

$M^2N^2 = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^4(x)}$ (**).

Multiplying (*) and (**) gives $M^2N^2(M^2-N^2-3) = 1$.

Comment: This was what i was talking about